# How do you dynamically load launch_url and append a relative path to it

Tags: nightwatch.js

I am trying to use the property `launch_url` in my tests and append a relative path to it before sending the browser to that url.

I know that `browser.init();` send the browser to the address in `launch_url` but I was wondering if it is possible to append some string to the retrieved url before executing the redirect.

Assuming my `launch_url` is `www.xxx.com`, I'd like to do something like:

```
this.test = function (client) {
    client.init("/a/b/c"); // >> should result in the browser going to www.xxx.com/a/b/c 
};
```

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever work this out?

Answer (score 11):

If you have specified a "launch_url" in your nightwatch.json file, you can access it on the 'client' object passed into your tests.  For example:

```
module.exports = {
    'Demo test Google' : function (client) {
        client
            .url(client.launch_url)
            .waitForElementVisible('body', 1000)
            .setValue('input[type=text]', 'nightwatch')
            .waitForElementVisible('button[name=btnG]', 1000)
            .click('button[name=btnG]')
            .pause(1000)
            .assert.containsText('#main', 'Night Watch')
            .end();
    }
};
```

So, for your example code:

```
this.test = function (client) {
  client.url(client.launch_url + "/a/b/c"); // >> should result in the browser going to www.xxx.com/a/b/c 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be to create a config file with some base items in it; then be able to append that config file through a custom init method you use.

IE:

```
var configDefaults = module.exports = {
   baseUrl: 'http://www.example.com/',
   local: false,
};
```

Then in your custom command write something like:

```
"use strict";
var config = require('./config')

exports.command = function(urlModifier) {
  var _self = this;
  _self
    .url(config.baseUrl+urlModifier)
    .waitForElementVisible('body', 4000)

  if( typeof callback === "function"){
    callback.call(_self);
  }
  return this;
};
```